# C++ comparing iterator with int

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, comparison, int

Is there a simple way to compare an iterator with an int?

I have a loop like this:

```
for (std::vector<mystruct>::const_iterator it = vec->begin(); it != vec->end(); ++it)
```

Instead of looping over the entire vector, I would like to just loop over the first 3 elements. However, the following does not compile:

```
for (std::vector<mystruct>::const_iterator it = vec->begin(); it < 3; ++it)
```

It there a good way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Arithmetic works: `it != vec->begin() + 3`

Comment: @DavidO would need to ensure that vec has more than 3 entries in it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since it's a vector, why not just access its position directly ?

```
if (vec->size() > 0)
{
    for (int i =0; i<3 && i< vec->size(); i++)
    {
        // vec[i] can be accessed directly
        //do stuff 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think this is the most clear of the proposed solutions, however the answer could use a bit of clean up: there's no need for the outer `if` test, and `vec.count()` should be written as `vec->size()`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::next(vec->begin(), 3);` will be the the iterator 3 places after the first, and so you can compare to it:

```
for (std::vector<mystruct>::const_iterator it = vec->begin(); it != std::next(vec->begin(), 3); ++it)
```

Your vector will need to have at least 3 elements inside it though.

Comment: +1. Using basic counter maybe an option too `(...;count < 3; count++,it++)`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: or more safely, `(...; count < 3 && it != vec->end(); ...)`

Comment: So, next is C++11 which is not so compatible.

Comment: @user788171 then use `operator+`. `vec->begin() + 3`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd want to be careful, because you can easily run into fencepost bugs.

This works on random access containers (like `vector` and `array`), but doesn't do ADL on `begin` because I'm lazy:

```
template<typename Container>
auto nth_element( Container&& c, std::size_t n )->decltype( std::begin(c) )
{
  auto retval = std::begin(c);
  std::size_t size = std::end(c) - retval;
  retval += std::min( size, n );
  return retval;
}
```

It returns `std::end(c)` if `n` is too big.

So you get:

```
for( auto it = vec->cbegin(); it != nth_element(vec, 3); ++it) {
   // code
}
```

which deals with vectors whose size is less than 3 gracefully.

The basic core of this is that on random access iterators, the difference of iterators is `ptrdiff_t` -- an integral type -- and you can add integral types to iterators to move around.  I just threw in a helper function, because you should only do non-trivial pointer arithmetic (and arithmetic on iterators is pointer arithmetic) in isolated functions if you can help it.

Supporting non-random access iterators is a matter of doing some traits checks.  I wouldn't worry about that unless you really need it.

Note that this answer depends on some C++11 features, but no obscure ones.  You'll need to `#include <iterator>` for `std::begin` and `std::end` and maybe `<algorithm>` for `std::min`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can simply go three elements past the beginning.

```
for (std::vector<mystruct>::const_iterator it = vec->cbegin(); it != vec->cbegin() + 3; ++it)
```

However, that might be error prone since you might try to access beyond the end in the case that the vector is fewer than 3 elements. I think you'd get an exception when that happens but you could prevent it by:

```
for(std::vector<mystruct>::const_iterator it = vec->cbegin(); it != vec->cend() && it != vec->cbegin() + 3; ++it)
```

Note the use of cbegin() and cend() since you asked for a const_iterator, although these are only available in c++11. You could just as easily use begin() and end() with your const_iterator.